# Detect strings that consist of some a's followed by some b's

Tags: c++, strings

This program needs to detect strings in which the first few characters are 'a', than few 'b'.
Is it possible that in this implementation may be undefined behavior.

```
string str; 
while (cin >> str) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (str[i] == 'a' && i < str.length()) {
        i++;
    }
    while (str[i] == 'b' && i < str.length()) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i == str.length()) {
        cout << "ok" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not ok" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly undefined behavior, but after the first `while` loop, `i` might be past the end of `str`. So in the condition of the second loop, you can get a segmentation fault or something. That would be in case when `str` is just `'a'` characters and nothing else.

Comment: I think what `kyrill` means is that you need to reverse the order of your tests.  `while (i < str.length() && str[i] == 'a')`

Comment: @LokiAstari, oh, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

```
// Note: str is a string.
//       containing "a"
//       So length = 1

while (str[i] == 'a' && i < str.length()) {
    i++;
}
// First Loop
//     str[0] == 'a' && 0 < 1
//     true && true
//     true
//       So we enter the loop body and increment i to 1.
// Second Loop
//     str[1]  // access beyond the end of the string.
//             // thus undefined behavior.
```

If we swap the test around

```
while (i < str.length() && str[i] == 'a') {
    i++;
}
// First Loop
//     0 < 1 && str[0] == 'a'
//     true && true
//     true
//       So we enter the loop body and increment i to 1.
// Second Loop
//     1 < 1  &&  // The left hand side of the test is false
//                // && is shortcut operator so the right hand
//                // side is not evaluated and the loop exited.
```

Comment: Strange; I would have thought C++ has these things such as out-of-range access standardized. (By standardized I don't mean "undefined behavior by the standard".)

Comment: @kyrill, if something goes wrong, safe assumption will be "it is undefined behavior". For out of range: there is `at()` function for vector for checked access.

Comment: @kyrill: We use `operator[]` when we know the value is in range and correct (so we don't have to pay the cost of testing it). We use the method `at()` when we don't know the value is in range and thus needs to be checked and throws an exception if the index is out of range.  The philosophy is those who are skilled at the language don't need to pay an extra cost just to babysit the beginners. The beginners can use the methods with the baby wheels to protect themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Under the circumstances, I think I'd "cheat" a little bit. To meet your criteria, the string needs to contain at least one `a` at the beginning, one `b` at the end, and it must be sorted (since there's nothing else between `a` and `b`, if it contains anything but `a`s and `b`s in order, it won't be sorted). that being the case, we can write the code something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names { "Not OK", "OK"};

auto okay = [](auto const &s) { return s.front() == 'a' && 
                                       s.back() == 'b' &&
                                       std::is_sorted(s.begin(), s.end(); };

cin >> str;
std::cout << names[okay(str)] << "\n";
```

Comment: Brilliant. But you don't even have to create a vector, you can just use ternary right in the (whatever it is... `[](…) { return…}`).

Comment: @kyrill: You don't *need* to, but IMO this is much more readable. Ternary operators are rarely a good idea. In addition, separation of concerns dictates that the lambda should only determine whether the string meets the criteria or not; it shouldn't deal with something I/O oriented like converting that to a string.